# Función flecha está renderizando componentes mapeados antes de obtener los datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-axios

Estoy usando el componente `<Get/>` de `react-axios` para hacer una petición GET a una API como se observa a continuación:

```
const {Get} from 'react-axios';
const React, {useState} from 'react';

const listComponents = props => {

//useStates, useEffects, entre otras cosas.
const [datos, setDatos] = useState(null);

const listComponents = datos.map(elem => {
    //Cualquier cosa para renderizar con un mapeado...
    return <p>{elem.name}</p>
});

return(
<Get url="/api/user" params={{id: "12345"}}>
    {(error, response, isLoading, makeRequest, axios) => {
        if(error) {
            return (
                <div>
                    Something bad happened: {error.message}
                </div>)
          }
          else if(isLoading) {
            return (<div>Loading...</div>)
          }
          else if(response !== null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {listComponents}
                </div>)
          }
          return (<div>Default message before request is made.</div>)
        }}
</Get>
)
}
```

Esto arroja el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Para el map de esa lista, ya que el array de datos es nulo.

Entiendo de mi problema es que la función que mapea se ejecuta antes de que llegue al render, es decir, esto no es imperativo... Pero quiero hacer eso, que se renderice esa lista solo cuando se obtengan los datos... Como pueden ver esto es un componente funcional...

Comment: El código tal cual está no compila, tienes un `const` al inicio "suelto". Además, usar `listComponents` para definir una función flecha y a la vez resusar el nombre dentro de la función funciona pero confunde a cualquiera que lea el código. Son detalles que hacen dudar a quien lea la pregunta, te recomiendo editarla y mejorarla

Comment: Gracias, la revisaré y la editaré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dices, el `map` se ejecuta antes del `return` (piensa que en los componentes funcional todo el código es como un gran render). Hay que tener en cuenta que el `useState(null)` inicial provoca un renderizado que hace que se ejecute el `map` y trate de hacerlo sobre una variable a null (de ahí el error).

Podrías hacer dos cosas:

1. Setear tu estado `datos` a array vacío. Así te aseguras de que el `map` no te va a dar error (simplemente te devolverá otro array vacío).
2. Comprobar que tu estado es distinto de null. En tu variable `listComponents` comprueba que `datos` no sea `null` para hacer el `map`:

   ```
   const listComponents = listComponents ? datos.map(elem => {
   return <p>{elem.name}</p>}) : null;
   ```

Personalmente me gusta más la primera. Si tu estado va a ser siempre un `array` tiene sentido iniciarlo a vacío.

Por cierto, `listComponents` no es una función tal y como lo tienes. Es una variable.

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón, estoy descuidando la inicialización y validación de las variables. Eso me sirvió de mucho.